# Logic question, "embedding" deduction theorem into PA?

Tags: logic

Suppose $T$ is recursively axiomatised in a finite language, $T$ extends the theory $N$. Assume further $T$ extends PA. Let $D$ be a closed formula in $T$, and let $T'$ be the theory $T[D]$.

Suppose $B^T$ represents, with variables $x,y$, the recursive predicate $Prf_T(a,b)$, which means $b$ is Godel number for a proof of $a$.

$A^T$ is the formula $\exists yB^T$.

Show that for any formula E, $T\vdash A^{T^{'}}_x[\underline{\ulcorner E\urcorner}]\Leftrightarrow A^T_x[\underline{\ulcorner D\rightarrow E\urcorner}]$, where $\underline{a}$ is the term in T, for example $\underline 3$ is $SSS0$.

I know the three derivability conditions, and I know it looks like deduction theorem, but I do not know how to show this is provable in T. Deduction theorem says $\vdash D\rightarrow E$ iff  $[D]\vdash E$ for any theory.

I have $PA\vdash (A^{T^{'}}_x[\underline{\ulcorner D\rightarrow E\urcorner}] \land A^{T^{'}}_x[\underline{\ulcorner D\urcorner}])\rightarrow A^{T^{'}}_x[\underline{\ulcorner E\urcorner}]$ by second derivability, but I don't know how to continue, especially how to connect $A^{T^{'}}_x$ with $A^T_x$.

Comment: We have algorithms to produce a proof $T[D]\vdash E$ from a proof $T\vdash D\to E$ and vice-versa. These can be formulated in PA..

Comment: @Berci so ur saying if there is a model M of T, then we interpret the equivalence sentence to get a proof number for A_x^T[D->E], and then we compute a proof number for A_x^T'[E]?

Comment: Not exactly, but sort of. Say $b$ is the Gödel number of a proof of $T\vdash D\to E$, then this proof is a sequence of formulas, the algorithm simply decodes its input as a sequence of formulas, inserts two formulas at the end, namely $D$ and $E$, and thus it will be a sequence of formulas which is a proof of $T[D]\vdash E$, and finally encodes this sequence using its Gödel number. The algorithm in the other direction is more sophisticated, but ultimately, I guess, it can be produced in a similar manner.